# Find maximum within moving subset in large dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, max, subset

I have a large dataframe (1000x1000) and I want to find all the maximas within subsets.

```
mat = diag(10-abs(-10:10))  # test matrix
```

I was trying to use a `for` loop to for the next 3 steps but it didn't work:

1. extract successive 3x3 subsets,
2. find the maximum within each,
3. then change all values of the subset to 0 and the maximum to 1.

Code

```
for (x in (1+2):(nrow(mat)-2)){ 
    for (y in (1+2):(ncol(mat)-2)){
        subset = mat[x:(x+2), y:(y+2)]
        wm = which.max(subset)
        mat[row(subset)[wm], col(subset)[wm]] == 1
    }}
```

Any advice/correction is welcome :-)

Comment: Overlapping subsets as well?

Comment: yes, with a shift of 1 row or column between each subset

Comment: But if you take overlapping subsets and change the values in each step to 0 an 1, your next subset will already be manipulated when finding its max. Is that what you want?

Comment: not really, I imagined doing this binarisation at the end after all the maximas have been found across the dataframe

Comment: You seem to be using the terms "data frame" and "matrix" interchangeably. Don't. This will be much more efficient on a matrix than a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
set.seed(123)
m<-matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=10)
m.max<- matrix(0, ncol=ncol(m), nrow=nrow(m))
for(i in 2:(nrow(m)-1)){
  for(j in 2:(ncol(m)-1)){
    subset<-m[(i-1):(i+1),(j-1):(j+1)]
    idx <-which(subset == max(subset), arr.ind = TRUE)
    m.max[(i+idx[1]-2),(j+idx[2]-2)]<-1
  }
}
m.max
```

Note that there is not necessarily a new "1" produced in each step, because the maximum of two overlapping subsets can be the same entry.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works great on your example. What is the purpose of the `-2` in the last line?

Comment: So (i,j) corresponds to the center of the current 3x3 subset as index of the big matrix. If now the maximum of the subset lies for example at (3,3) in the subset, this means that you have to go 1 to the right and 1 down from the center. That's why, at least in the way I am indexing, you have to subtract -2 for row and column, respectively.

Comment: say we select a 5x5 subset, all 2's become 5? I guess the `idx[2]` would not change?

Comment: The idx[2] would stay, but the -2's in the last would become -3's. If the subset is a nxn matrix, the number you subtract will be (n+1)/2.